# Blazor Dynamic Input Fields DataBinding

Tags: blazor

I am trying to understand databinding but cannot figure out the best way to achieve this.

My component is very simple:

```
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ResetValues">Reset values</button>

<br />

<div class="row">
@for(int i=1; i<=NumberOfContacts; i++)
{
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-md">
    </div>
}
</div>
@code{
    [Parameter]
    public int NumberOfContacts {get; set;}


    public void ResetValues()
    {
        // how to reset dynamically generated input field values
    }
}

//In Index page, I am simply going:
<Contacts NumberOfContacts="3" />
```

It correctly produces the number of input fields I define (on index page within parameter), but how do I bind values such that I am able to read them and clear them on reset button click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ResetValues">Reset values</button>

<br />

<div class="row">
@for(int i=0; i<NumberOfContacts; i++)
{
    @* Never use the loop variable directly *@
    int local=i; 

    @* Add a key to help Blazor track things *@
    <div class="col bg-success" @key=local> 
        @* Bind to an array element *@
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" @bind=contacts[local]> 
    </div>
}
</div>
```

```cs
@code{
    [Parameter]
    public int NumberOfContacts {get; set;}

    // Bind this to the inputs
    string[] contacts;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Make sure to initialise the contacts array
        ResetValues();
    }

    public void ResetValues()
    {
        contacts = new string[NumberOfContacts];        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and providing a workable code as well.  It is much appreciated.  It is useful for me to see usage of the OnInitialized() method and I will ensure to read up on component lifecycle.